# Report Visibility on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, report

I have an Object called Sales Target whose OWD is set to private. Using Role hirerachy I created a Managment team lead and I have added a user. Using sharing settings I have given access to this sales target object to the user Role. When trying to open an report with sales target included this user is not able to see the report. One thing to be noted is this user's profile doesn't have access to the Sales Target object.  I just want to know why the user is not able to see the data eventhough he can open the report.

Answer (score 1):

Org-Wide Defaults do not override Profile-level CRUD and FLS access. Those layers are *lower* in the Salesforce security model.

You must provide object- and field-level access to your profile before the record-level access granted by the OWD and Role Hierarchy has any effect.

Comment: I did give the profile level and field level access still seeing no data under it